# Want to ASP classic page without HTML to be not shown

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript, window, show

In my scenario, I have an ASP classic page that is being called. I want that to not show to the user  the ASP classic page. The ASP classic page only has VBScript code, I think this could ease solving this issue. Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: It is usually helpful to say what you *do* want to happen as well as what you don't want to happen.

Comment: Is that VBScript code server side Classic ASP or client side Internet Explorer code? (I'd assume the former, but it helps to be explicit).

Comment: So just use Response.Redirect when you are done and the user will never know he visited that page.

Answer (score 0):

What should the enduser see? If the page is being called by a user-interaction the enduser expects *something* back from the browser. If you don't want to show an empty page, you should at least redirect to the homepage but a page with more usefull information about the user-interaction would probably be better.

Anyway, you can use either ***response.transfer*** or ***response.redirect*** to do the redirect.
Response.transfer is a redirect on the server-side, response.redirect on the client-side.

Comment: The enduser interacts with an Asp page, then  that Asp page autosubmits itself a form, and calls the page without html. Then the page without html calls another Asp page. I have mentioned three pages. Only the firs one and the last one are the ones which the user should see. The second one, the Asp page without HTML should not bee seen by the user.

Comment: I need to made this little weird things because:
-The first Asp classic page calss first an Asp.Net page and afterwards the second Asp classic page.
-The second Asp classic page (the one without HTML), waits till the Asp.Net accomplishes a goal. Then the second Asp classic page calls the third Asp classic page.

Comment: Hard to follow but this all sounds like that autosubmit should be done with an Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like it should be done using ajax calls.  One thing you can do is post an additional value to your asp page and on that 2nd asp page test for the value or response.redirect to some other page.

Let's say you are sending values to page2.asp like page2.asp?data1=abc&data2=xyz.  You can change that to page2.asp?data1=abc&data2=xyz&specialkey=hawks

Then on your page2.asp at the top of the page insert the code

```
if request("specialkey")<>"hawks" then
    response.redirect("home.asp")
end if
```